# Undefined control sequence `\includegraphics`

Tags: graphics

I understand a number of people have asked similar questions to this but I am yet to find an answer in their questions which solves the problem I'm having.

I am trying to put an image into a pdf. I have done this plenty of times and never had any major issues.

This is some of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[margin=1in] {geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath { {D:\Work\Thesis\Images} }

\begin{document}
\title{Developing...}

\section{xx}

\subsection{xx}

\includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{vv1.jpg} 

\end{document}
```

I have checked the directory of the image clearly and the image name and both are correct. I have tried putting the image in a different document and its worked just fine.

Comment: Have you tried \graphicspath{D:/Work/Thesis/Images}?

Comment: When you say `\include graphics` in the question title, with a space, that causes me to suspect that this space could be the reason behind the error. Just a wild guess.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which error message(s) do you get?

Comment: @Masroor: The command `\includegraphics` is correctly spelled in the MWE, however.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I did notice that, but I was surprised why it is written that way in the subject. Again, just a wild guess.

Comment: Even though your operating system, Windows, uses a backslash for delimiting directories in a path, `\graphicspath` always expects a forward slash. See [Heiko's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186400/21891).

Comment: @Masroor: Well, I refrained from editing the 'typo'(?) In the title, but it was my first guess also

Comment: Hi, turns out switching from backslashes to forward slashes and including the directory separator has sorted the issue. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\graphicspath { {D:\Work\Thesis\Images} }
```

TeX will look for macros `\Work`, `\Thesis`, and `\Images`.
You can use forward slashes instead (also in Windows):

```
\graphicspath{{D:/Work/Thesis/Images/}}
```

Also you need the directory separator at the end of the path, because package `graphicx` only puts the path before the image name.

The additional set of curly braces is correct.