# How do I correct an Undefined Control Sequence when using includegraphics?

Tags: includegraphics

I understand this my concern has been expressed previously [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327213/memoir-class-graphicx-resizebox),`[here2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186396/undefined-control-sequence-includegraphics) and [here3](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/Undefined_control_sequence) but the responses cannot still solve my problem.

I included an image in my Latex code, which was running normally until today. All attempts only show undefined control sequence.\includegraphics{IDP}. I have checked for errors, retyped the code without any luck. It seems there is something I am not doing right.

I would very much appreciate any assistance on how to correct my code.

Here is the code I am using

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[strict]{csquotes}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\includegraphics{IDP}
\caption*{Source:~\citeA{dunning1996investment}}
\caption{Patterns of Investment Development}
\label{figIDP}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Put a `\usepackage{graphicx}` in your preamble if not there yet, does the error persist?

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me... Please make sure that the minimal example throws the same error as the complete document.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I have included a minimal code, still trying to find out how to add the png image

Comment: @BeriParfait You don't need to upload the image. We can test replacing it by `example-image` (unless the problem is with the picture itself, which doesn't seem to be the case here).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik The code has been working fine for six months since I started writing my thesis. It's only today I had a break down with it.

Comment: @BeriParfait (Things like to break when a thesis is underway ;-) Did you update your TeX distribution today? If you did, something may have changed (although unlikely). If you did not, then try deleting temporary files. As I said, it's hard to tell without a code that throws the error.

Comment: Welcome to here. Can you post the exact error with a few lines of context from before it? If you replace `IDP` with `example-image-a`, does the minimal example you posted above compile then?

Comment: the error you show is not the format of a tex error message, please show the exact error from the log with all lines in a code block (`{} ` button)  so line endings are preserved.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle See non-answer below? Should this be a different question or combined with this one?

Comment: please don't post clarifications to teh questions as answers, you can edit the questiion, again you need to mark the code block as without the original line endings it is impossible to read the error message (the line break marks which command is undefined)

Comment: This is almost certainly the standard miktex issue (the only thing I know about miktex:-) have you updated _both_ user and admin versions of miktex If you only update one you will get inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: It seems that MikTeX updated the `graphics` package (https://miktex.org/packages/graphics) but not the LaTeX base (https://miktex.org/packages/ltxbase). https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/131

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This time I don't think it is. It seems like MikTeX just didn't update the LaTeX base, but did update the `graphics` package. See my comment above.

Comment: Today's update should resolve the issue. Make sure to run the MikTeX updater in Admin and User mode.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I did update Tex on that day, and it was immediately after the update that I realised the code could no longer run properly. The messages shows that "Process exited with error(s)"  while the log only shows " Undefined control sequence \includegraphics{IDP}.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. The directory to which the question has been resolved was helpful. I look forward to a permanent solution from the next MikTex update.

Comment: my guess above was wrong (it happens:-) this was not the usual user-error with only updating miktex in one of the two modes, it was an error in miktex, with graphics updated but not the base latex code to match.